# Memory issue during JAR execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, out-of-memory, spring-cloud, jvm-hotspot

I have about 8 API's JAR and 4 from spring cloud (Zuul,Hystrix,Config-Server,Eureka). I am running all the jars in one server right now though we will scale up later when going to production.

The AWS Linux server has a 16GB memory. The problem I am having is the server constantly runs out of memory for some reason and when i try to execute a Jar I get below error.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000078fb80000, 293601280, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

The error is not specific to specific jar it is random.

Memory from server (Currently I have 9 jars deployed ):-

```
free -m

             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15630       13684        1835          17         110        1781
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue. Can provide more info if any other information is required.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could try to do a Flight Recording, 
java -XX:StartFlightRecording=settings=profile,filename=recording.jfr,dumponexit=true <jar-files> (JDK8u40) and open in Java Mission Control. JFR may run into problem on OOM, but many times it will succeed. Look at Object Statistics to see what kind of objects that fills the heap, or Allocation Statistics (if there are very large objects) or information about native memory, garbage collection etc may give a clue,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the java arguments to the execution jobs which seems to solve the problem .

**java -Xmx64m -Xss256k -jar abc.jar**

After this even though I had 13 jars deployed on the same server I had 10GB worth of memory left and which was 1.7GB before I added the arguments.

***Memory Before JAVA arguments:***

```
free -m

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:          15630       13684        1835          17         110        1781
```

---

**Memory After Java Arguments:**

---

```
free -m

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:          15630        4927        8769          25        1932       10373
```

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when the JVM attempts to use more memory and is available and the OS refuses after the program has started. I would try reducing the heap size to give the system more free memory.

You have almost no buffer/cache used which suggest to me that there are times when your free memory is less than this size. (Just not when you took this sample)

How much free swap space does this machine have?

Comment: I am not a server person so how do i check the swap space... I just modified the execution command to test out in the server--> **java -Xmx64m -Xss256k -jar jarname.jar**

lets see how this goes.

Comment: @Grinish The problem is how much free memory the system has. A small program can fail if there isn't much free memory (even momentarily)

Comment: I agree.. The issue is basically it is not suppose to use that much but still it is using a lot of memory...based on this article https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/10/spring-boot-memory-performance
 I should have a lot of space left in my machine...

Comment: @Grinish If you have around 20% free memory and no swapping, I would agree in most cases.